# Multiple objects horizontally in listbox VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, object, listbox

I would like to add multiple objects in a listbox. I want the object to show horizontally.

I did something like this

```
ToDoList.Items.Insert(0, currTask.Priority() & currTask.TheDate())
```

But it doesn't work because it only accepts one object at the same time apparently.
Is there a way to store the object in an array and then call the array as the object in the listbox?

Thank you.

Comment: try: `ToDoList.Items.Insert(0, String.Fomat("{0}    {1}", currTask.Priority(), currTask.TheDate()))`  They wont line up as columns though

Comment: Format is not a member of 'String'.

Comment: sure it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx it is not however a member of `VisualBasic.StringS`

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio. How can I make it work in VisualBasic?

Comment: make sure autocomplete used `String.Format` (singular) nor `Strings...`

Comment: Answer the question so that I can rate it up.
Again, thank you very much

Comment: The problem was that I copied and pasted your code and you wrote 'Fomat' instead of 'Format'